# SqlAlchemy gives interface error when connecting to redshift from Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am using sqlalchemy to connect to redshift cluster. I am able to read the tables in one warehouse. But when I change to a different warehouse, the code fails saying there is a password error. The exact error message is as follows:

```
InterfaceError: (redshift_connector.error.InterfaceError) {'S': 'FATAL', 'C': '28000', 'M': 'password authentication failed for user "<user_id>"', 'F': '../src/pg/src/backend/libpq/auth.c', 'L': '418', 'R': 'auth_failed'}
```

Steps I did:

1. Verified that the pwd works when logging in through console
2. Ensured there is an inbound rule permitting tcp requests from external environments for the security group
3. Ensured the cluster is publicly accessible
4. Found an identical error [reported](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/issues/481) in aws datawrangler a few years back. The solution there said special characters in password would cause it, and so I updated my password to just alphanumeric.
5. I have also tried redshift-connector library instead of sqlalchemy, and still am facing same error.

But the error still remains. Has anyone else faced similar issue? At a broader level, I just want to connect to redshift from an external python environment. So a workaround of this error with any alternative solution too is helpful.

**Edit/Solution:**

Okay, this is embarassing. I was using iam user id and pwd for connection, while I should be using db user name and pwd. Leaving it here in case someone in future does similar mistake.

Comment: Is there any difference in how the Redshift clusters are configured?  Something like one requiring SSL for connections?

Comment: Both the clusters come from two different clients, so they aren't identical. But as far as I could check in the cluster properties, the settings all match quite well. I may not be checking something but I don't know what it is.

Comment: do both have the same setting for "require SSL"?

Comment: Both the clusters have require ssl as false. I looked at all the other paramters too in the warehouse paramters group. They look identical.

Comment: I assume credentials to these clusters differ too since different client. did you check if correct password being picked up in code for another warehouse/cluster access ?
If you are running python code manually by explicitly adding password for testing then plz ignore this comment.

Comment: Ya, the pwd is correct :)